# Indexing all files and directories of a FTP server?

Tags: windows, ftp

I found some open FTP servers that allow anonymous login. Is there any software on Windows that can recursively index all available files and directories of a FTP server?

Comment: with "index" you mean a list of file names on these ftp-servers?

Comment: Yes I meant that listing all the files and directories on these FTP servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Windows versions of [`lftp`](http://redpark.posterous.com/lftp-for-windows) and [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

```
wget -r -nv --spider ftp://server/dir/
lftp -e "find .; exit" ftp://server/dir/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm using lftp and it works fine. However is there any way to tell the "find" command to output file size and date as well?

Comment: Not that I know of. The command `cls -l` will display date and size, but it won't recurse.